# How to use scripts from the public folder in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, webassembly

I have built some WASM (and some simple wrapper code) using rust and `wasm-pack`. Unfortunately putting this code in the `src` folder causes it to be processed by webpack, which breaks. I'm using create-react-app and I don't want to eject (precisely because I don't want to learn how to work with or configure webpack).

There are many github issues devoted to solving this issue with more libraries, which seem to also not work (or work for some people but not others, or etc.). The standard libraries don't seem to interact very well, and while they will probably get better with time, the fact is that in simple JS, we can do this simply. For example in https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html we see that we can just use the generated code as an npm package on its own, no problem, so long as we're not using webpack.

So my idea is to just put this code in the `public` folder, have it delivered to the client as-is without packing, and be done. However I can't figure out the syntax for actually importing code from those folders. How do I do it?

Note that the possible duplicates I found are about importing images or etc. from the public folder, using `<link>` or etc., but I don't believe that solves my use-case, since I need those javascript objects and their associated functions, to call in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rust-webpack-template](https://github.com/rustwasm/rust-webpack-template). It is a kickstarter which embedded rust-wasm-pack with webpack.

After that you can simply add react + babel in webpack by follow this
[tuto](https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/#babel-react-setup). There are some minors changes in webpack.config.js to do.

I used this for my own litte project with rust + react. [My repo](https://github.com/sepiropht/tic-tac-toe-wasm).